# Rotate a face in a Three.js geometry

Tags: javascript, three.js

Hi I'm trying to make a torsional distortion using threejs. What I have is a cylinder where I want to rotate one of its end and let the other fixed, so I can recreate this effect.

What I have: [Current shape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZPnS.png)

What I want: [Desired shape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMLFJ.png)

What I want to know is if there is a function that I can use to make the desired modification over the geometry, I have tried and I didn't find any.

```
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
camera.position.z = 100;
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
var geometry = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(50, 50, 1000, 20);
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({wireframe: true});
var cylinder = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
cylinder.rotation.z = Math.PI/2;
scene.add( cylinder );
```

Comment: Mesh edges cannot curve. It must be simulated. I am just thinking off the top of my head, you'd actually want many invisible cylinders lined up in a row like plates. Each side face of a cylinder is connected to the corresponding side face on the next cylinder by a line. You can use the face normals to find the side faces. You would then rotate any cylinder in the line and have a rule set on how to propagate the rotation value down the line of cylinders in either direction. A squeeze property could be interpolated from the reduction of radius created by the center point of the connecting lines.

Comment: You would have to write the function yourself that modified the vertices and normals of the original geometry. Alternatively, you can create a custom `ShaderMaterial` that modified the geometry in the vertex shader.